# sql insert query with condition - not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add data to a table with the condition - if data is already exist - don't add it. I don't want to use `INSERT IGNORE INTO`

**SQL:**

```
INSERT INTO `alerts` (type, userID, fromID, refID, createDate) 
    VALUES ('commentReply', 2, 1, 452, 1443048940) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                        FROM alerts 
                        WHERE `type` = 'commentReply' 
                        AND userID = 2 
                        AND viewed = 0
                        )
```

**Error:**

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;** check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM alerts WHERE `type` =
>   'commentR' at line 3

Does anyone know what is wrong with my statement?

Comment: `INSERT` does not have a `WHERE` clause. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

Let my answer your question

If you use WHERE NOT EXIST you need to write the code in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO alerts (type,id,....)
SELECT 'COL1 VALUE', 'COL2 VALUE'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE COL1='COL1 VALUE');
```

Or you can use another way to do it.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alerts WHERE yourcondition > 0)
  UPDATE alerts SET c1=(SELECT id FROM beta WHERE yourcondition)
ELSE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO alerts (names..) VALUES (values...)
END
```